# how to open the androidx source code in android studio

Tags: android

I occurred this mistakes when I follow the procedures by the androidx GitHub page

when I execute this command ./gradlew studio then it occurred error bellow

```
ould not find com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.7.2.
```

Searched in the following locations:
- file:/Users/edz/androidx-main/prebuilts/androidx/external/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.7.2/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.7.2.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
unspecified:unspecified:unspecified

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.